# filter list variable in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

In general how do we filter by a list variable in dplyr?

E.g. a data frame where one variable is a list of different classes of object:

```
aa <- tibble(ss = c(1,2),
             dd = list(NA,
                       matrix(data = c(1,2,3,4),
                              nrow = 2,
                              ncol = 2)))

> aa
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ss dd           
#  <dbl> <list>       
#1  1.00 <lgl [1]>    
#2  2.00 <dbl [2 × 2]>
```

For example if I want to filter for logicals (though could be anything), if it were not a list it would be as simple as:

```
aa %>% filter(is.logical(dd))
```

But this returns

```
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: ss <dbl>, dd <list>
```

Because it's not the first element that's a logical, it's the first element of the first element:

```
> is.logical(aa$dd[1])
# [1] FALSE
> is.logical(aa$dd[[1]])
# [1] TRUE
```

One may use `purrr:map` for other operations on nested list variables, but this also doesn't work.

```
> aa %>% filter(map(.x = dd,
+                   .f = is.logical))
# Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : basic_string::resize
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the 'dd' is a `list` column, we can loop through the 'dd' using `map`, but each element of 'dd' can have more than one element, so we make a condition that if `all` the elements are `NA`, then `filter` the rows of the dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
aa %>%
   filter(map_lgl(dd, ~ .x %>%
                           is.na %>% 
                             all))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#     ss dd       
#   <dbl> <list>   
#1     1 <lgl [1]>
```

---

If this is about `filter`ing based on `class`.

```
aa %>%
    filter(map_lgl(dd, is.logical))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#     ss dd       
#  <dbl> <list>   
#1     1 <lgl [1]>
```

In the OP's code, `map` output is still a `list`, we convert it to a logical vector with `map_lgl`

Comment: Great answer. Works only for logicals though, while I'm really looking for a general method for filtering list variables. Question  edited to make this clear

Comment: @rubadubdub  Thanks for clarification.  I updated the output

Answer (score 2):

The best I can do is to create a dummy variable using `is.logical` with `purrr:map`, `unlist` it, `filter` by it, then un-`select` the dummy variable. Works, but what a kerfuffle.

```
aa %>%
  mutate(ff = map(.x = dd,
                       .f = is.logical),
         ff = unlist(ff)) %>%
  filter(ff == TRUE) %>%
  select(-ff)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
#      ss dd       
#   <dbl> <list>   
# 1  1.00 <lgl [1]>
```